# Provided *.pb, how to know the model has fully connected layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model, *.pb, 
How do I know whether it uses fully connected layers.

I have looked for `dense` keyword (tf.layer.dense), not sure whether it is right.

I am new to TF, any help is appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By visualizing the graph in tensorboard will be helpful.